# Permitir Download em Aplicativo IOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, webview

Comecei a desenvolver para IOS e não consigo realizar o download dentro de uma WebView Utilizando o Xcode na linguagem Swift.

O Código é bem simples, ele abre um site, onde contem um botão para baixar um arquivo de Imagem.

Porém após clicar no botão, ele abre a imagem em uma página branca.
Se eu pressionar a imagem, ele aparece a opção de salvar, mas quanto eu clico o Emulador fecha e aparece uma mensagem de Erro (`Thread 9: signal SIGABRT`).

Já revirei a internet de cabeça para baixo e olhei em outras respostas aqui mesmo no Stack Overflow, mas nada funcionou pra mim.

```swift
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {


    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func loadView() {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let myURL = URL(string:"https://erroemdownloadios.com")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.load(myRequest)


    } 
}
```

Comment: Por que é urgente?

Comment: Olá, Anderson. 
Sou desenvolvedor Web, e um cliente meu me deu um ultimato, para desenvolver o aplicativo em IOS, pois senão, cancelaria o sistema.

Comment: Quando ele te contratou falou que precisava fazer para o iOS tb?

Comment: Não, mas acabou surgindo essa necessidade e preciso desenvolver esse aplicativo, pois tenho outro cliente que também está cogitando essa hipótese.
Já Desenvolvi três aplicativos para Android, mas me deparei com esse empecilho, entrando em um ambiente que não estou acostumado. 
Você poderia me ajudar Hugo ?

Comment: @Davi Você deve estar recebendo SIGABIRT do emulador porque seu app precisa de `NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription` no seu Info.plist. Quando a ação de salvar no celular é ativada de dentro do seu app, o OS pede, através do seu app, ao usuário permissão para salvar a imagem. Experimente colocar essa chave e ver se o crash some.

Comment: Olá Igor, obrigado pela resposta. Adicionei no Info.plist  uma Key com nome: NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription  com o tipo String. Infelizmente o erro continua :(

Comment: Tente "Privacy - Photo Library Additions Usage Description" e "Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description"

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta George, Ele parou de fechar o Emulador, mas eu fui verificar nas pastas e ele não salvou a imagem. Você poderia me ajudar com isso ?

Comment: Tem sim, mas tem que verificar qual método você esta utilizando pra salvar esta imagem, talvez seja melhor criar outra pergunta com mais detalhamento.

Answer (score 1):

Eu lhe recomendaria fazer com que seu ViewController implemente `WKNavigationDelegate`. Nessa delegate, você pode usar o método:

```swift
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void)
```

No `navigationAction`, você consegue pegar a URL para o qual o browser vai navegar. Caso seja uma imagem (você pode saber isso pelo `pathExtension` ou alguma outra regex na URL), você pode usar baixar a imagem via código (com `URLSession` ou `Data`), e salvar nas photos do usuário.

**EDIT (13/09/2019):**

Você pode interceptar as mudanças de URL dessa forma:

```swift
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {


    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func loadView() {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.naivgationDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let myURL = URL(string:"https://erroemdownloadios.com")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.load(myRequest)


    } 

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        guard let requestURL = navigationAction.request.url else {
            decisionHandler(.allow)
            return
        }

        //Aqui você tem a URL, e pode fazer o que quiser com ela.

        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }
}
```

Comment: Bom Dia Igor, obrigado pela resposta.

Não consegui realizar a Ação, eu acrescentei no código da seguinte maneira: 




class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate,WKNavigationDelegate{
      var webView: WKWebView!
    
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void){

    }

 Você poderia me dizer se está correto?

Comment: @Davi Eu atualizei minha resposta para incluir como usar as actions.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda  Igor, eu realizei o teste e infelizmente o erro ainda persiste. ele Retorna: Thread 10: signal SIGABRT e Fecha a aplicação.  :(